# FindFirstFileA function caching the result

Tags: c, windows, file, directory

I want to keep listing the files in a Windows directory and want to check the API calls being made by [FindFirstFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea) and [FindNextFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilea?redirectedfrom=MSDN) functions. I see the API call which is used under the hood for the first time it is done. But for subsequent calls, I don't see any API call happening even though the directory is listed multiple times. My guess is that there is some caching that happens with these methods but can't find anything online that would help me disable it. Any help with this?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for [Directory Change Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/obtaining-directory-change-notifications)?

Comment: Please explain what you mean with the phrases "check API calls" and "see the API call".

Comment: So, I am actually looking for the system call that is used behind the scenes when this method is run. I want to evaluate the calls that are made whenever this method is run. For the first time, I see the corresponding system call, but for subsequent runs, I do not see anything that shows up.

Comment: ZwQueryDirectoryFile called internal and this api call can return multiple files in bufer, for single call ( exist parameter for this )